# How do you use SINTERSTORE and ZINTERSTORE from a redis client in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using the node_redis library 
https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis
There are very few examples given on how to use SINTERSTORE/SUNIONSTORE and ZINTERSTORE/ZUNIONSTORE, there are no examples on how to pass the parameters for these functions in the client.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found the correct way to do it

```
var redis=require('redis');
var client=redis.createClient();
client.on('connect',function () {
console.log('connected');
});
client.sadd('sa', 'a');
client.sadd('sa', 'b');
client.sadd('sa', 'c');

client.sadd('sb', 'b');
client.sadd('sb', 'c');
client.sadd('sb', 'd');

client.SINTER(['sa', 'sb'], function (err, intersection) {
    console.log(intersection[0]+" "+intersection[1]);
});

client.ZINTERSTORE('sc','2','sa', 'sb', function (err, intersection) {
    console.log(intersection);
});

client.ZRANGEBYSCORE('sc','-inf','inf',function (err,reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

Just provide the input in the order given in the redis documentation